# sql Query on effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to get report for drink purchased in whole month but price of the drink can change any time in month and I would like to get report for a month with price change

I have two tables

```
SELECT  [ID]
      ,[DrinkID]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[qty]
      ,[DateTaken]
  FROM [Snacks].[dbo].[DrinkHistory]

SELECT  [ID]
      ,[DrinkID]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[qty]
      ,[DateTaken]
  FROM [Snacks].[dbo].[DrinkHistory]
```

**[DrinkHistory]**:

```
ID             DrinkID     UserID          qty         DateTaken
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
1               1               1               1           2014-05-10  
2               1               1               2           2014-05-15  
3               2               1               1           2014-06-01  
4               2               1               4           2014-06-01  
5               1               1               3           2014-05-20  
6               1               1               4           2014-05-30
```

**[DrinkPricesEffect]**:

```
PriceID        DrinkID         DrinkPrice      PriceEffectiveDate         IsCurrent
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               10.00             2014-05-01    1
2               1               20.00             2014-05-20    1
3               2               9.00              2014-06-01    1 
4               2               8.00              2014-01-01    1
5               1               30.00             2014-05-25    1
6               1               40.00             2014-05-28    1
```

I would like to have result as under date taken between 2014-05-1 to 2014-05-31

```
DrinkId Qty    Price    DateTaken       PriceEffectiveDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1       10      2014-05-10          2014-05-01  
1   2       10      2014-05-15          2014-05-01  
1   3   20      2014-05-20          2014-05-20  
1   4   40      2014-05-30          2014-05-28
```

Is there any who can give me some idea or write query for me?

Comment: What have you got so far?  There's a number of related questions on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drink price can change any time in a month you could additionaly save the price for each purchase. I would add a column [PricePaid] to the table [DrinkHistory].

When adding a record to [DrinkHistory], the price for the drink at the moment is known, but later it might change so you save the current price to the history...

Then for your result you could just display the Whole [DrinkHistory]

```
SELECT * FROM DrinkHistory;
```

Comment: any other solution if some time effective date entry is made wrong or if it is to be edited then at that time it may create problem

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Select 
    DH.DrinkId,
    DH.Qty,
    DPE.DrinkPrice AS Price,
    DH.DateTaken,
    DPE.PriceEffectiveDate
FROM DrinkHistory DH
JOIN DrinkPricesEffect DPE ON DPE.PriceID = 
(
  Select Top 1 PriceID FROM
  (
    Select PriceID,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PriceEffectiveDate DESC ) AS rnk
    FROM  DrinkPricesEffect
    WHERE DH.DrinkId = DrinkId AND
          DH.DateTaken >= PriceEffectiveDate

  )SubQ WHERE rnk = 1
) 
WHERE DH.DateTaken Between '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-30'
```

Here you can find the SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f8fb/26/0